# How do I bind a volume in docker-compose to a host directory?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to sync files when I change them inside the volume.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: someimage
    volumes:
      - code:/code

volumes:
  code:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /Users/me/work/web
```

I don't want to do

```
services:
  web:
    image: someimage
    volumes:
      - /Users/me/work/web:/code
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using mac, windows and linux. But currently testing on a mac 12.3.1

Comment: What's wrong with the short syntax?  (The volume does not pass through to the underlying image; if the volume exists and you rebuild the image with changed code, those changes will be hidden by the volume.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment David, I'm aware of that. It's a bit difficult to explain why I need this in a single comment so I ask you to just go with it. What I struggle with is finding documentation regarding the OS specific driver options available for a volume through `docker compose`. What I'd like is to have a synced volume with a host dir that doesn't depend on the container.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen did you ever find out how to make it work with docker-compose ?

Comment: @TarunParmar no